# If `threading` module doesn't really let multiple threads run at once due to GIL, why is ParallelPython using all my cores?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

AFAIK, the `threading.Thread` instances can't actually run in parallell, due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), which forces only one thread to be able to run at any time (except for when blocking on I/O operations).

[ParalellPython](http://www.parallelpython.com/) uses the `threading` module.

If I however submit multiple local jobs to it, it DOES execute them in parallel, or at least so it would seem.
I have 8 cores, and if I start 8 jobs to simply run empty loops, they all take up 12-13% of the CPU (meaning they each get executed on one core, and I can see this in my task manager)

Does anyone know how this can happen?

Answer (score 6):

As the linked page says,

> **PP** module overcomes this limitation and provides a simple way to write parallel python applications. Internally `ppsmp` uses processes and IPC (Inter Process Communications) to organize parallel computations

So the actual parallelism must be due to invoking multiple processes, as one would expect.

Comment: In short: in Python, multithreading can't be truly parallel, but multiprocessing (more than one full process running at once) can.

Comment: @Anorov In short in **cpython** multithreading can't be truly parallel and even that is only an implementation detail. There used to be a patch that replaced the GIL with more finegrained locks and allowed for parallelism. The problem was that single threaded programs ran a good bit slower (especially under linux with the old locks..) so it wasn't considered worthy for the mainbranch. But things can change..